# Visual Studio 2010 - Error CODE 22

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

Upon trying to compile a program I get an error MSB3073: The command *_* exited with code 22.

What does code 22 mean? Btw, the *_* is not the actual command. I am just leaving the command out.

Edit: typo fix: MSB3073

Answer (score 1):

MSB3073 is a postbuild error, so you should check the "Compilation Events" (for post-build tasks) of the project. It could be a typo in those events since "_" is not a cmd.exe usual command.

Comment: The _ is not the command that is run. I just left out the command.

Comment: How would I go about checking the compilation events?

Comment: Well, at least the postbuild commands are executed in a standard command interpreter (cmd.exe), you could try to reproduce the command and look for the error. Looking for the 22 error, it's a bit strange, beacause usually, cmd.exe just returns the standard errors: http://www.febooti.com/products/automation-workshop/online-help/events/run-dos-cmd-command/exit-codes/ ¿are you setting in the postbuild commands the %ERRORLEVEL% value?